# Ng-Repeat does not repeat (or return anything)

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and still playing around with it at this point. To teach myself the concepts, I am working off of a few hand-constructed JSON files.

I first used it to construct the elements of a pop-out javascript menu by using ng-repeat on a list element where the controller accesses a JSON file. That worked fine. I then tried to ng-repeat a rather complicated table row structure over a different JSON file with a slightly more complicated data model. At runtime, this returns a comment, as with the previous experiment, but no elements to go along with it.

I am using two controllers as part of one app. I think the issue may be in how the data from the JSON files is accessed.

Not including the CSS as I don't *think* that's impacting it. The 'MenuCtrl' controller is still functioning correctly (ng-app is called on the  element of the whole page), so I'm only including what I feel is the relevant HTML.

controllers.js:

```
  var profileApp = angular.module('profileApp', []);
  profileApp.controller('BookCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('books.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.bookItems = data;
    });
  });
  profileApp.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('profile.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.profileItems = data;
    });
  });
```

books.json:

```
[
  {
"title": "The Design of Everyday Things",
"author": "Donald Norman",
"img": "img/norman.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",
"id1": "hoverA",
"id2": "hover1"
  },
  {
"title": "Plans and Situated Actions",
"author": "Lucille Suchman",
"img": "img/planssitu.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",
"id1": "hoverB",
"id2": "hover2"
  },
  {
"title": "Where The Action Is",
"author": "Paul Dourish",
"img": "img/wheretheaction.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",
"id1": "hoverC",
"id2": "hover3"
  },
  {
"title": "Information Processing and Human-Machine Interaction",
"author": "Jens Rasmussen",
"img": "img/rasmussen.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",  
"id1": "hoverD",
"id2": "hover4"
  },
  {
"title": "The Imaginary App",
"author": "Paul D. Miller and Svitlana Matviyenko",
"img": "img/imaginary.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",
"id1": "hoverE",
"id2": "hover5"
  },
  {
"title": "The Gutenberg Galaxy",
"author": "Marshall Mcluhan",
"img": "img/guten.jpg",
"isbn": "",
"description":".",
"id1": "hoverF",
"id2": "hover6"
  }
]
```

Relevant portion of HTML:

```
<div  align="center">
<p class="central">Bibliography</br></p></br>
<table class="content1" ng-controller="BookCtrl" >
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" class="col1">
        <col span="1.5" class="col2">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody ng-repeat="book in bookItems" >
    <tr >
        <td align="center"><div class="center"><div class="round3"><a href=""><img class="book" ng-src="{{book.img}}"></img></a></div></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="wrapword" style="padding-left:10px;"><p><span class="content2"><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></span>
            <span class="small2">{{book.author}}</br>
            <span class="hide2" id="{{book.id1}"}>See Description</span>
            <span class="hide" id="{{book.id2}}">{{book.description}}</span>
            </span>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What I get when inspecting the elements of the running page:

```
<table class="content1 ng-scope" ng-controller="BookCtrl">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" class="col1">
        <col span="1.5" class="col2">
    </colgroup>
    <!-- ngRepeat: book in bookItems -->
</table>
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: One problem is that you are using `ng-repeat` on the tbody element, which should be defined once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see some mark up that is not valid but I think your code breaks because of this invalid mark up: `<span class="hide2" id="{{book.id1}"}>See Description</span>`, change to            `<span class="hide2" id="{{book.id1}}">See Description</span>`

Comment: It was actually a combination between what you suggested (I stared at this for a while and did not catch that!) and Aviro's sugestion below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned, ng-repeat inside TBODY, which I corrected. This should work now.

```
<div  align="center">
<p class="central">Bibliography</br></p></br>
<table class="content1" ng-controller="BookCtrl" >
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" class="col1">
        <col span="1.5" class="col2">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody  >
    <tr ng-repeat="book in bookItems">
        <td align="center"><div class="center"><div class="round3"><a href=""><img class="book" ng-src="{{book.img}}"></img></a></div></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="wrapword" style="padding-left:10px;"><p><span class="content2"><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></span>
            <span class="small2">{{book.author}}</br>
            <span class="hide2" id="{{book.id1}"}>See Description</span>
            <span class="hide" id="{{book.id2}}">{{book.description}}</span>
            </span>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```